# Loop self.array addObject iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c

It is a table view controller cell
I need to add item by

```
[self.array addObject:@"1"];
[self.array addObject:@"2"];
[self.array addObject:@"3"];
[self.array addObject:@"4"];
```

how can I do it by for loop?
I have try

```
for(NSInteger i=1;i<5;i++){
[self.array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

but it errors

Comment: what are the errors? But try using [self.array addObject:i]; in the for loop, not @(i)

Comment: @() will box an int as an NSNumber, not an NSString.  To use @() and get an NSString object, you'd have to sprintf() or itoa() the int into a char*

Answer (score 0):

Probably the errors have something to do with format? In the first example you gave, you added the objects as strings, I don't see that in the second. I'd try like this:

```
for(NSInteger i=1;i<5;i++){
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)i];
    [self.array addObject:string];
}
```

Comment: Incidentally you could have an empty loop body and stuff this all in one line.